# Deploy fails because can't move 'current' symlink from releases folder

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano3

When deployment gets to "deploy:symlink:release" it fails because apparently the current release symlink is interpreted as a folder, so the "mv" command (without -r) refuses to move it. I'm deploying to a Mac, this is the error log:

```
00:33 deploy:symlink:release
      01 ln -s /Users/jean/www/rails_app/app/releases/20180120135811 /Users/jean/www/rails_app/app/releases/current
    ✔ 01 jean@blizzard.local 0.171s
      02 mv /Users/jean/www/rails_app/app/releases/current /Users/jean/www/rails_app/app
      02 mv: rename /Users/jean/www/rails_app/app/releases/current to /Users/jean/www/rails_app/app/current: Is a directory

(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as jean@blizzard.local: mv exit status: 1
mv stdout: mv: rename /Users/jean/www/rails_app/app/releases/current to /Users/jean/www/rails_app/app/current: Is a directory
mv stderr: Nothing written
```